# data persisting outside of a function call using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to query data from my postgresql database. I'm using pg and I query the data using client.query. I'm successfully making the query, but I lose the data when I leave the function called by client.query. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the await, but I need that to get it working.

```
var data;
const connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:postgres@storedb.csyjfyng5vgc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/clientdb';
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: connectionString
});
await client.connect();
await client.query('SELECT * from public.clients', function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("This is the Error")
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
    client.end();
    data = res.rows;    
});

console.log("data", data);
```

res.rows gives me the array that I want, but when I set it to data, data is undefined. Console.log("data", data) returns:

```
data undefined
```

How can I make this data persist outside of the function called by client.query?

Comment: Don't pass a callback if you expect it to return a promise that you want to `await`.

Answer (score 2):

`client.query` only work with await if return a Promise:
https://node-postgres.com/api/client#client.query

```
var data;
const connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:postgres@storedb.csyjfyng5vgc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/clientdb';
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: connectionString
});
await client.connect();
let res = await client.query('SELECT * from public.clients');

data = res.rows;    

console.log("data", data);
```